# Checkbox HTML array is empty PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, input

**EDIT: I never got this working, it appears that *"boxes"* was not an array on the PHP side, instead was a String that said "Array." I switched to an AJAX solution and no longer need this answer. It will now be closed**

So, this seems like a very simple question, but I have checkboxes generated from php in a form, then re-submitted to a php script for processing. Unfortunately, the array of checkboxes is EMPTY.

Here is my generated form code. (**NOTE**: the action is empty because its the same php file):

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="multi" value="1"> <-- Ignore this -->
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="1">  <-- Ignore this -->
<input type="hidden" name="EMAIL" value="sample@example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="FNAME" value="John">

<input type="checkbox" name="boxes[]" value="Jennifer and Friends"> Jennifer and Friends<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxes[]" value="Worship with Rachel"> Worship with Rachel<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxes[]" value="Jim Gerhold: Relationship"> Jim Gerhold: Relationship<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxes[]" value="Maximize Others Leadership Resources" checked=""> Maximize Others Leadership Resources<br>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Now when I print_r the $_POST array I get the following input:

```
Array
(
    [multi] => 1
    [test] => 1
    [EMAIL] => <REMOVED>
    [FNAME] => <REMOVED>
    [boxes] => Array
)
```

And... in the chrome developer tool, I see the form data correctly:

[image: Chrome Form Data]

And finally, a var_dump of $_POST['boxes'] returns

> string(5) “Array”

Does anyone know how to retrieve the array, or why it is not appearing as a normal php array?

Comment: What is your question? Also, you should post your PHP too.

Comment: How do you know its empty? Try `var_dump` instead of print_r

Comment: by the looks of it, it's not empty, it has an array type inside it [boxes] => Array

Comment: try this var_dump($_POST['boxes']); to see if the array is empty

Comment: @Nicolas My question is why cant I transverse the array. My php right now is just the print_r. var_dump returns string(5) “Array”. It seems like the contents is "Array". If I echo $_POST['boxes'][0] it returns 'A', then 'r'... and eventually prints Array

Comment: @JonathanSchoberJr. It would be useful to edit your question with the above suggestions in mind. i.e. 1) Put the actual question in you question, 2) Show the output of `vardump($_POST)` in your question, and 3) show any PHP code that might be operating on `$_POST` up until the point which you output its contents.

Answer (score 2):

It's not empty, and I quote directly from your `print_r($_POST)` output:

```
[boxes] => Array
```

You can loop through the contents with:

```
foreach($_POST["boxes"]) { ... }
```

or print the contents using:

```
print_r($_POST["boxes"]);
```

---

While it is outside the scope of your question, I would recommend using [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) next time. `var_dump` traverses sub-arrays and formats nicely in `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: Running a var_dump returns string(5) “Array”.